# Prevent people from wildcard redirecting to my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to prevent users from creating wildcard redirects on their websites to mine.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

My site is in PHP. I am willing to add PHP code or edit my htaccess to make this possible.

Thank you for the assistance.

I've tried forcing a page refresh, but the nature of my website would cause an infinite loop to occur.

Comment: This is not possible in a reliable (robust) manner. The only option you have is to evaluate the "referrer" header that is sent by browsers when they are redirected in a classical way. You could then either block such requests (which make people think _your_ page is broken since it is _your_ URL that is visible in the browser's address bar). Or you could again redirect the request to a page that explains the issue (which will only annoy users, since it is neither their fault nor anything they can change). In addition a clever redirection will work undetected by that strategy.

Comment: You should ask yourself if you really want to invest into that attempt. What for? In the end you published something on the internet. Now users access what you published. Why does it matter _how_ they reach what you published?

Comment: And about the attempt you wrote you made yourself: what should a page refresh achieve in that situation? How ever you tried to implement that?